# Can Grafana monitor endpoints?

Tags: grafana

I have a REST API and I would like to check the health of specific endpoints. Can Grafana be used to monitor the health of specific endpoints? Any plugins that can be used for that? I know that it can be integrated with Zabbix, are there any other ways to do it?
Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That really depends what `to monitor the health of specific endpoints` means for you. Usually it is:

1. metric collecting: No, that is not a native task for Grafana. There was special Worldping plugin for Grafana https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/raintank-worldping-app, but that is deprecated. Usually your monitoring tool (Zabbix, Prometheus, Dynatrace, ...) is doing this.
2. metric visualization: Yes, this is the best task for Grafana. It can visualize metrics from supported time series databases/apps
3. alerting: Yes - but only in the graph panel, so there is overhead - you need to manage dashboards/panels for every single metric just to have alerting. Again, monitoring tools have usually better design for this task.

=> Use monitoring tools for monitoring and use Grafana just for the graphs.

Comment: Thank you! I am quite new to this so this is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

You can probably look at Prometheus blackbox exporter and use that to monitor the health of your endpoint.

https://github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter

Prometheus can then be added as a data source in Grafana and then Yes you have to first create a dashboard/panel if you want to use Grafana alerting capability.